# Embed an IE window in a C# form?

Tags: c#

How can I go about doing this?  I am new to C# so my knowledge is fairly limited.  I'm creating a Screensaver with C#, and wish to embed an interactive IE window in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the WebBrowser control:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should have searched MSDN, it's pretty easy to find a [list of user controls .NET framework has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfak08ea.aspx) where you can find the WebBrowser control. However, are you sure you want this? If you just want to open a webpage as a screensaver, wouldn't you rather just launch the URL in the default system browser? In that case, you can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method to launch the URL in the default browser, whatever it is.